# Azure REST API - Server failed to authenticate

Tags: c#, azure, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, sha256

I'm creating Windows Phone 8.1 Store App with ability to upload some blobs into Azure Storage. I cannot use WindowsAzure.Storage lib (very weird), so I'm trying to use REST. I cannot figure out, what's wrong.

```
try
{
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string tosign = "GET\n" +
                        "\n" +  //Content-Encoding
                        "\n" +  //Content-Language
                        "0\n" +  //Content-Length
                        "\n" +  //Content-MD5
                        "\n" +  //Content-Type
                        "\n" +  //Date
                        "\n" +  //If-modified-since
                        "\n" +  //If-match
                        "\n" +  //If-none-match
                        "\n" +  //If-unmodified-since
                        "\n" +  //Range
                        "x-ms-date:" + time + "\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n" +   //CanonicalizedHeaders
                        "/storage_name/\ncomp:list";    //CanonicalizedResource

    string hashKey = "DHpNuYG5MXhamfbKmFPClUlNi38QiM2uqIqz07pgvpv2gmXJRwxaMlcV05pFCYsrelGYKPed9QphyJ/YnUrh5w=="; //Primary access key

    MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
    var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(tosign, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(hashKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
    IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);
    string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", time);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "SharedKey storage_name:" + hashedString);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Error: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

How I can make it work?

Comment: I guess, I have an error in my crypto method.

Answer (score 3):

Your cryptography code is awry. :-)

## Code Samples

What follows are working code samples that "call the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm on the UTF-8-encoded signature string and encode the result as Base64." In the below samples, the `hashKey` parameter is the "Primary Access Key" from Azure and the `toSign` parameter is the "Signature String" from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx).

### Encoding the Signature on Windows Phone 8.1

On Windows Phone 8.1 we use the `Windows.Security.Cryptography` namespace like this:

```
public string GetEncodedSignature(string toSign, string hashKey)
{
    // UTF-8-encoded signature string
    var utf8 = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
    var msgBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toSign, utf8);

    // primary access key
    // note the use of DecodeFromBase64String
    var keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(hashKey);

    // make the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm
    var alg = MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256;
    var objMacProv = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(alg);
    CryptographicHash hash = objMacProv.CreateHash(keyBuffer);

    // call the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm
    hash.Append(msgBuffer);
    IBuffer hashMsg = hash.GetValueAndReset();

    // retrieve the result!
    var result = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashMsg);

    return result;
}
```

## Encoding the Signature in .NET

I also created [an example for .NET](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSjFwc) that uses the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace.

```
public static string GetEncodedSignature(string toSign, string hashKey)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(hashKey);
    var utf8encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSign);
    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
    {
        bytes = hmac.ComputeHash(utf8encodedString);
    }

    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return signature;
}
```

Both code samples produce the same encoded signature when given the same inputs. You can see one of them in more detail at this [Fiddle that generates the HTTP Request](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSjFwc).

## See Also

[MSDN Article Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've already worked this out but if not or for anyone else, I've just had the same issue and for me what fixed it is changing the Content-Length to "\n" (instead of "0\n"). From version 2015-02-21 and later you don't need to specify the length.

```
try
{
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string tosign = "GET\n" +
                        "\n" +  //Content-Encoding
                        "\n" +  //Content-Language
                        "\n" +  //Content-Length
                        "\n" +  //Content-MD5
                        "\n" +  //Content-Type
                        "\n" +  //Date
                        "\n" +  //If-modified-since
                        "\n" +  //If-match
                        "\n" +  //If-none-match
                        "\n" +  //If-unmodified-since
                        "\n" +  //Range
                        "x-ms-date:" + time + "\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n" +   //CanonicalizedHeaders
                        "/storage_name/\ncomp:list";    //CanonicalizedResource

    string hashKey = "DHpNuYG5MXhamfbKmFPClUlNi38QiM2uqIqz07pgvpv2gmXJRwxaMlcV05pFCYsrelGYKPed9QphyJ/YnUrh5w=="; //Primary access key


   string hashedString = GetEncodedSignature(tosign, hashKey); //Shaun's answer method

    var client = new HttpClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", time);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "SharedKey storage_name:" + hashedString);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```